# How to adjust vertical Spacing as defined by document setup

Tags: spacing

I am hoping to get some assistance with removing vertical space in my LaTeC document.

The second block of code shows seemingly simple code... so I'm not sure where the spacing (before the **section** begins) is coming from.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template 

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[ small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customized lists
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep} % Make itemize lists more compact

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}} % roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{Integrated Science Curriculum -- December 2021} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{titling} % Customizing the title section

\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries} % Article title formatting

\posttitle{\end{center}} 

\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newsavebox\mysavebox
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Article title closing formatting
\title{\centering{Pathogen Resistance of 
\textit{Saccharomyces cerevisiae}}
\LARGE{-- Support For Mutation Hypothesis In Eukaryota}
} % Article title

\author{%
\textsc{Test \small{Test} }\\[1ex] % Your name
\normalsize Test\\ 
}
\date{\today} % Leave empty to omit a date
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}
{%
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
}
 
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\textbf{\section{Background}}

\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\textbf{\section{Background}}` is not proper.  `\section{\textbf{Background}}` might work; however, you should not have to *manually* change the font series (bf) of the `\section` command, if you define your sectioning commands properly.  Whether any of this fixes the problem you are having is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, `\textbf{\section{Background}}` is not proper. In fact reversing the order, `\section{\textbf{Background}}` nominally fixes the issue.  However, that itself is not the best approach, either.  Better still is the following changes:  remove the `\textbf` from the `\section` argument altogether and instead place `\bfseries` as part of the titleformat:

```
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\bfseries\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{}
```

Here is the revised MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext} % Package to generate dummy text throughout this template 

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
\linespread{1.05} % Line spacing - Palatino needs more space between lines
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[english]{babel} % Language hyphenation and typographical rules

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage[ small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} % Custom captions under/above floats in tables or figures
\usepackage{booktabs} % Horizontal rules in tables

\usepackage{lettrine} % The lettrine is the first enlarged letter at the beginning of the text

\usepackage{enumitem} % Customized lists
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep} % Make itemize lists more compact

\usepackage{abstract} % Allows abstract customization
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} % Set the "Abstract" text to bold
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape} % Set the abstract itself to small italic text

\usepackage{titlesec} % Allows customization of titles
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}} % Roman numerals for the sections
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\roman{subsection}} % roman numerals for subsections
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\scshape\bfseries\centering}{\thesection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\large}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{} % Change the look of the section titles

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[C]{Integrated Science Curriculum -- December 2021} % Custom header text
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\usepackage{titling} % Customizing the title section

\usepackage{hyperref} % For hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up

\pretitle{\begin{center}\Huge\bfseries} % Article title formatting

\posttitle{\end{center}} 

\setlength\parindent{24pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newsavebox\mysavebox
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Article title closing formatting
\title{\centering{Pathogen Resistance of 
\textit{Saccharomyces cerevisiae}}
\LARGE{-- Support For Mutation Hypothesis In Eukaryota}
} % Article title

\author{%
\textsc{Test \small{Test} }\\[1ex] % Your name
\normalsize Test\\ 
}
\date{\today} % Leave empty to omit a date
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}
{%
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}
}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Background}

\blindtext
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you really mean to just paste a big chunk of code without commentary as your answer?

Comment: @DonHosek No.  I add in stages.

Comment: @DonHosek & Steven:  Wow; thank you for such detailed and helpful comments -- something I can really learn from! Thank you so much... can't wait until I too can give back. Cheers!